# Identical solr queries finds things based on one field but not based on another

Tags: solr

I am having trouble with solr searches, it appears some fields are not working and I can't understand why. Lets say I have this object (there is a lot of data here that can be ignored, but I didn't want to cut it out in case it was relevant).

```
{
    "category":["INFOGRAPHIC"],
    "user_ref":"F_6fd87c",
    "first_name_text":["Erik"],
    "location_text":["AM  "],
    "_ts":5972482969498025988,
    "recommended_by":["E_45588d"],
    "hourly_rate_text":["100"],
    "is_staff_recommended":false,
    "ns":"users_db.solr_portfolios",
    "last_name_text":["Freelancer"],
    "title_text":["Really 50"],
    "description_text":["."],
    "is_recommended":true,
    "_id":"F_6fd87c:portfolio-XgPaREUfhuYp",
    "_version_":1458125725674504192
}
```

I can successfully hit this document by doing a query like:

```
select?q=category:INFOGRAPHIC
```

However, the following query will NOT hit the document:

```
select?q=hourly_rate_text:100
```

Why not? I'm not very skilled in solr so I might be missing something completely obvious, but what is the difference between these two fields? Both contain a string, I query with a perfect match on the string, how can it not find it? I even tried setting the field to "ASD" just to be sure it was not the numbers that somehow messed it up.

Solr gives me headaches...

Comment: you should provide relevant definitions of the fields in schema.xml

Comment: Can you post the field and fieldtype definition for category and hourly_rate_text.

Comment: It depends on the field type. Follow the comment shere -- post your field definitions from schema.xml. More than likely, you've either (a) used an odd field type, or (b) you're not indexing the value.

Comment: Ah, I thought the field type was the same as they looked the same. I will check for it and post what I find.

Comment: Doh, there was an incorrect wildcard thing in the schema that prevented the field from being indexed. Thanks people, didn't think to check that.

Comment: Or rather I assumed that anything that was stored in solr was indexed, perhaps a bad assumption :P